# Создание двумерного массива в excel

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть *исходный* *массив*, где каждый столбец - это год [image: массив_1]

У меня есть параметр (например **N**), который задает, с какого года в строке будет появляться значение, то есть я могу сдвигать значение ячейки раньше/позже

А теперь вопрос: для каждой такой строки *исходного массива* мне нужно формировать *новый двумерный массив* (верхняя треугольная матрица), где происходит смещение по строкам и столбцам на значение параметра **N**

[image: массив_2]

Что хочется сделать: при изменении параметра **N**, данные массивы автоматически пересчитывались

Пример при **N** = 3

[image: массив_3]

Пример при **N** = 5[image: массив_4]

Результат выводится ниже на несколько сот строк на том же листе

Желательно формулами, но и макросом будет интересно посмотреть, если не сложно

Comment: Непонятно... Обычно таблица имеет "шапку". Так сразу видно, какой столбец что содержит. Как формируется массив из строки? Как сопоставить Ваши рисунки? Куда выводить массивы? Только формулами или можно макросом? Не стесняйтесь объяснять. Покажите пример с определенным *n* (возможно, несколько -  для разных *n*

Comment: Добавил 2 примера при N =3 и N = 5

Comment: Теперь понятнее. Количество столбцов с годами статично? Ведь размер массивов по вертикали (по строкам) зависит от количества столбцов с годами. В исходном массиве первые два столбца пустык, третий с одним значением. Это что? Их учитывать?

Comment: Кол-во столбцов с годами статично. _Базовая строка №1_ из примера - это одна из строк _исходного массива_. То есть мне нужно будет сгенерировать столько массивов (верхнетреугольных матриц), сколько строк в _исходном массиве_. Соответственно меняя **N** мы будем сдвигать количество активных столбцов для последующего расчета массива. В _исходном массиве_ **N** для первых 6 строк равно 3 и для 7-ой строки равно 2.

Comment: Опять непонятно... N может быть разным для разных строк?

Comment: Да, совершенно верно.

Comment: N для строки - положение первого значения в строке?

Comment: Да, или, например, через сколько лет начинается деятельность/активность/ что угодно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вариант для одной строки** исходных данных. Формулу вставить в *B11*, копировать на весь диапазон треугольной матрицы (на весь блок):

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ЕСЛИ($O$2>СТРОКА(A1);;ЕСЛИ($O$2+СТОЛБЕЦ(A1)-СТРОКА(A1)>0;ИНДЕКС($B$2:$N$2;$O$2+СТОЛБЕЦ(A1)-СТРОКА(A1));));)
```

где *$B$2:$N$2* - данные строки, *$O$2* - *n+1* для строки, вычисляется формулой:

```
=СЧИТАТЬПУСТОТЫ(B2:N2)+1
```

Для всех строк исходных данных формулу копировать в верхнюю левую ячейку диапазона для треугольной матрицы (*B11*, *B24*...), заменить *$O$2* и *$B$2:$N$2* на диапазоны из нужной строки.

**Одной формулой для всех матриц.**

Для облегчения расчетов (и понимания формулы) используются доп. вычисления в трех столбцах. Можно все в одной формуле, но при этом то, что вычислялось в одной ячейке, будет просчитываться в 13 формулах (по несколько раз в одной).

Формулы вносятся в строку 11 и протягиваются на нужный диапазон строк (естественно, при другом количестве строк в исходных данных формулы нужно будет писать не в 11 строку).

-- *О11* - n+1 для каждого блока:

```
=ИНДЕКС($O$2:$O$10;$P11)
```

или без диапазона *$O$2:$O$10*:

```
=СЧИТАТЬПУСТОТЫ(ИНДЕКС($B$2:$N$10;$P11;))+1
```

-- *P11* - номер блока:

```
=ЦЕЛОЕ((СТРОКА()-11)/13)+1
```

универсальнее - определять количество столбцов в исходных данных:

```
=ЦЕЛОЕ((СТРОКА(A1)-1)/СЧЁТ($B$1:$N$1))+1
```

-- *Q11* - номер строки в блоке:

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИ($P$11:$P11;$P11)
```

-- *B11* - основная формула:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ЕСЛИ($O11>$Q11;;ЕСЛИ($O11+СТОЛБЕЦ(A1)-$Q11>0;ИНДЕКС($B$2:$N$10;$P11;$O11+СТОЛБЕЦ(A1)-$Q11);));)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, решение вижу, сейчас разберусь, применю в своих вычислениях

Comment: Супер, спасибо!